# Ларавел 5.2 auth user id

Tags: php, laravel

в Laravel не могу получить `user id`. Версия Laravel 5.2. Возвращает такое `fd61b05c-8a6f-494a-b429-29a11444a0ea` 
при `dd(Auth::user()->id);`

Answer (score 0):

1) Убедитесь, что у вас подключен класс `use Auth;` в этом контроллере

2) Проверьте, что у вас лежит в БД в таблице с пользователями? Может в поле `id` действительно хранится символьный хэш.

3) Выведите всю информацию о пользователе `dd(Auth::user());` и посмотрите что лежит в `attributes`

Comment: При dd(Auth::user()); возврашает все информацию из ДБ, кроме ид не понимаю в чем дела

Comment: @ЖораХзмалян попробуйте dd(Auth::id());

Comment: @ЖораХзмалян и что в БД? что хранится в поле id?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rscx0k 
В базу хранится ид авто инкрумент https://prnt.sc/rscxle вот так

Comment: @ЖораХзмалян такое ощущение, что когда Вы создавали микрацию для вашей сущности указали -     $table->uuid('id')->primary(); Если есть возможность, приведите более подробный код, обновив Ваш вопрос.